# Run a MySQL query trough pressing a link and escaping backslash

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP code below that prints the result of a MySQL query in a HTML table. Furthermore, in the table, I create a link of the result that will be used in another query. Lets take a look at the code:

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "DB1");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fileDB";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>filename</th>";
                echo "<th>filepath</th>";
                echo "<th>size</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><a href='http://mysecreturl.com/test.php?path=" . $row['filepath'] . "'>" . $row['filename'] . "<a/></td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['filepath'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['size'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

This code works as intended, but now comes the problem: I want to implement the following: Once you click on the link, another query should be executed, this one to be specific: `SELECT * FROM fileDB WHERE filepath = 'the one sent from the link'`. I thought to use something like `$_GET["filepath"]` from the link to set the filepath in the second query. I have two main problems with this:

1. I don't know any PHP so I have no idea how clicking a link could run another query and generate a new table with results.
2. This is important to point out, filepath is a string of a Windows path, therefore it contains backslashes like this: `C:\something\something` etc. When I query this manually in phpMyAdmin I escape the backslashes by writing `C:\\something\\something` but when getting my result in the table from the code above, the string filepath will have one pair of backslash of course (as it is saved in the database). How could I then perform my second query if the backslashes apparently need to be escaped?

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or prepared statements.

Comment: Actually, just prepared statements. Stop using deprecated, bad practice. Read up on "prepared statements", and the PHP just needs a form with `method="get"` to fetch the content you need (when a user click a "link" (really a button in a form in the table) then it gets pasted to the link, and parsed from there. This is pretty simple PHP / Form-control, with added SQL on the server side.

Comment: The file test.php, is this the same file as in your question?

Comment: @SloanThrasher Yes it is!

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I thought so, and thought I could go towards prepared statements once I understand the concept. But as I understand it is the best way to go from start here. Could you please help me with this? I would appreciate it so much! I don't even need a button, the second query should run directly as you press the link and give another set of result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought you want to download a file. well this is much simpler:

```
if (isset($_GET["path"])) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT * FROM fileDB WHERE filepath = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_GET["path"]);          
}else{
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT * FROM fileDB");      
}
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

if ($result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt)) {
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    ...
```

---

oh and one more thing you should escape query component in your URL

```
echo "<td><a href='http://mysecreturl.com/test.php?path=" . urlencode($row['filepath']) . "'>" . $row['filename'] . "<a/></td>";
```

Comment: All right, I think we are close now, the only problem is that when I press on the link it only updates the page but the new query is not executed, and I am not getting a new set of results. Why is that? @Peter

Comment: Ok, I fixed it by changing the link to test.php?filepath= but not it is returning No records matching your query were found. Why is that? I tested the query manually and it worked? Is it not escaping backslashes or something?

Comment: @L.S works for me. change `$_GET['filepath']` to `$_GET['path']` http://i.sshot.ninja/0B7e9.jpg i missed that you have ?path= instead ?filepath= in href

Comment: @L.S also I really really suggest object oriented mysqli. procedural mysqli is just pure headache

Comment: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", str_replace('\\','\\\/',$_GET["path"]));` I think this is what you want for escaping backlashes. @L.S

Comment: @HK007 hell no. you don't touch strings at all. that's the reason for prepared statements

Comment: Then how  are you going to escape backlashes ? @Peter

Comment: @HK007 DBMS is doing it, that's the whole reason why to use prepared statements. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement developer should not care about doing it. escaping strings manually is old dark ages of php.

Comment: @Pete Everything is now working fine, I really appreciate your help! You point out stuff you don't like but you back it up with facts!! Thanks man!

Comment: @L.S sorry for being a pain but you should really consider using `id` instead of filepath like i mentioned in other answer where I thought you want to download file. If this is public application it will blow into your face. Not only attackers are aware about your directory structure, queries are slower but if you'll chose to change filepaths one days all sites linking to your site will be out-of-dated

Comment: @Peter Nah, you are actually helping me a lot! I am using this only for myself, but it will be online and therefore your point about the directory structure is valid! I will consider to change to ID or maybe hash the path string?

Comment: @L.S no just use auto increment ID, that's the best option. Everybody does that. Some sites like youtube or imgur use char string for ID like `6Pjpj` because they handle milions of people and you can compress much much more ID's in shorter string. A-Z+0-9 is 36 long so you can compress 36^5 in 5-char string compared to 10^5 if you use digits only. ?id=53245761283 is not sexy at all :)) but iirc facebook does that

Answer (score 1):

Now this could be done using get method like `<a href="yourpage.php?path='your_filepath'">` then in your php use this `<?php if(isset($_GET['filepath'])){//Run your php query here}?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
echo '<tr>
 <td><form method="get" action="test.php">
       <button type="submit" name="path" value="'.$row['filepath'].'">
'.$row['filename'].'</button>
</form></td>
<td>'.$row['filepath'].'</td>
<td>'.$row['size'].'</td>
</tr>';
```

Untested, but should in theory work. Why you have the link in the filename-table-cell, instead of in the table-cell with the actual path in it, god knows, but you can test it and see if it works.

I would, however, just make this into a $_POST, unless it's important to show the URI in the address bar.

Comment: Meh - missing an end quote - must've not gotten included when I copied. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question, you can add variables to a link, e.g. if you want to pass a first name and last name in a link you would do this

```
<?php
$fname = "John"; // First name
$lname = "Doe"; // Last Name

echo "<a href='next_table.php?fname=$fname&lname=$lname'>Next Table</a>";
?>
```

Then to retrieve the first name and last name on another page you would use this:

```
<?php
$fname = $_GET["fname"];
$lname = $_GET["lname"];
?>
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: You can't use in-string variables with single quote string

Comment: True, I guess the vodka Russian Standard is to blame.

Answer (score 0):

Just an if statement to check whether the **filepath** is set or not and `str_replace` function to escape backlashes.

```
   <?php
    /* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
    server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "DB1");

    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Attempt select query execution 
    // Check If filpath is set or not
    if(!isset($_GET['filepath']))
    { 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM fileDB";
    }
   else
    {

    $filepath=$_GET['filepath'];
    //replace backlashes with double backlashes using str_replace
    $filepath=str_replace('\\','\\\/',$filepath);  
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM fileDB WHERE filepath='$filepath'";
    }
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th>filename</th>";
                    echo "<th>filepath</th>";
                    echo "<th>size</th>";
                echo "</tr>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td><a href='http://mysecreturl.com/test.php?path=" . $row['filepath'] . "'>" . $row['filename'] . "<a/></td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['filepath'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['size'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
            // Free result set
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        } else{
            echo "No records matching your query were found.";
        }
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }



// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: please use prepared statements, this is a must. let's not teach new people bad practices.

Comment: @Peter I beg, could you please show me how this shall be done? I promise to read up on PHP and Prepared Statements once I finish this!

Comment: Well I am also new and I was solving his problem with the best of my current knowledge.

Comment: @Peter, if you (I'm guessing) are going to down vote other answers because their answers don't use prepared statements, at least add an answer that uses them.

Comment: The one that will provide me an answer solving my problem with prepared statements will receive an upvote and the answer will get accepted.

Comment: @SloanThrasher will do

Answer (score -1):

Change the code:

```
// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fileDB";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
```

To:

```
// Attempt select query execution
if(isset($_REQUEST['file']) && $_REQUEST['file'] !='') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM fileDB WHERE `file` = '".$_REQUEST['file']."';";
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM fileDB";
}
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
```

This should convey the basic idea, but take to heart about using parameterized queries.

Comment: please use prepared statements, this is a must. let's not teach new people bad practices.

Comment: Agreed, but the OP is new and I was trying to illustrate one of the many things he needs to understand. Keeping it simple.